# Android reader that will ignore PDFs, use my directory structure?

Tags: ebook-management, android

I have an Android tablet (ASUS) that I use for reading PDF files (mostly scientific papers) using Adobe Reader.  It works well for that, and I have a thousand or so papers on it, indexed in my own directory structure.

I would like to read epub files too - mostly older works from Project Gutenberg, at least to start.  I tried using the built-in app (called "MyLibrary") but it did a search of memory and dumped every one of those papers, and other PDF files like backup copies of my tax forms, into one flat list.

Is there a reader that will let me tell it to look for ebooks only where I've put them?  So if I put ebooks in say /Removeable/MicroSD/Books, it will only look there, and ignore those thousand other files?

Comment: `dumped every one of those` - on the storage media, or on the screen? On my reader, there are several views:

Comment: @virolino: Thanks for the reply.  I meant that the readers I had tried up to the time of the question apparently scanned the entire storage media, looking for anything that would fit their definition of readable file.  I did finally find one.  Unfortunately, I can't tell you what it is at the moment, as the tablet fell on the floor, cracked the digitizer glass, and (thanks to Chinese New Year) it will be several more weeks before I get a replacement one.

Comment: Sorry for the loss :(. Happy New Chinese Year! :)